# Put focus on magicsuggests input element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, magicsuggest

I am not able to put focus on the magi8csuggests input element through java script, 
I even tried triggering FOCUS event on the Input element, but no success.
I created my magicsuggest by:

```
_ccSuggest=$("#ccSuggest").magicSuggest({
    resultAsString: true,
    dataUrlParams: 
    minChars: 1,
    displayField: 'fullname',
    selectionStacked: false,
    data: strUrl,
    typeDelay:400
});
```

Now I want to put focus in the Input element as soon as I open my div which holds this magic suggest. Any Help?

Thanks

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In following the official doc :  http://nicolasbize.github.io/magicsuggest/#tab-4

The author initialize with :

```
$('#ms-right').magicSuggest({
    width: 250,
    selectionPosition: 'right',
    data: 'red,orange,blue,purple,dark blue,yellow,green,magenta,cyan,black,white'
});
```

So to focus on the input :

```
$('#ms-right input').focus();
```

Tested with chrome v32.0.1700.107, it works...

Comment: Hey, actually my magic suggest was inside a drop-down div, so when the toggle happened for the drop down the focus even used to get lost.so i   used , setTimeout('$("#ms-right input").focus()', 700); and it worked